# Element not reacting to the data change - v-if not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to vue js. I have a code to toggle the heading when I click the "toggle heading" button. But I don't know why it is not working. I need your help.

```
<script setup>
let show_heading=true;
function toggleHeading(){
  show_heading^=true;
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1 v-if="show_heading">Hello world is working</h1>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="toggleHeading">Toggle heading</button>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Have a look at [how to declare reactive state](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html). You might have to tick the switch in the upper left to toggle documentation for composition api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on script setup part

```
import { ref } from 'vue';

const show_heading = ref(true);

function toggleHeading() {
   show_heading.value = !show_heading.value;
}
```

Or you can read this https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes for toggle. Just doing step by step.